# Why was my passport stamped on exiting Taiwan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, taiwan

I traveled first time to Taiwan in 2018. Entered with 90 day visa exempt. Upon leaving, I got no exit stamp on my passport.

I traveled there again few weeks ago, again entered on 90 day visa exempt. Left after 1 week for a weekend outside Taiwan, got again no exit stamp.

Reentered the day after my leave from above, got another 90 days visa exempt.

But this time upon leaving I got an exit stamp.

Is there a reason for this different procedure?

Comment: There have been many reports here of border officers all over the world not stamping when they should and stamping when they shouldn’t do this could just be an error. But I don’t know Taiwan policies on this so can’t say whether this was an error or if there’s a reason for that.

Comment: Perhaps because this trip you had exited and re-entered.